# Flair is not displayed at Area51 site proposal

Tags: support, status-bydesign, area-51, flair

Hello,

I have followed a web-site proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7418/android-development for the "Android Development".

AS i have followed this proposal, there should be my name with reputation displayed overthere, but it is not.

Any problem is there ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You followed the Android Development proposal on July 24, so you are not one of the 40 most recent followers.

Comment: You mean only first 40 followers listed in Followers list, right !! is it for every proposal ?

Comment: @Paresh The 40 people that *most recently* followed the proposal are displayed in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of commitment.

Following does not do this.

Comment: my question was that i should be displayed in "REcent Follower" list

Comment: @paresh oh, I see -- can you check again in a few hours to see? It might not be updated in real time.

Comment: The "Recent Followers" module is updated in real time, though you need to refresh after following or unfollowing.